# Minimal distance between a point and a manifold M (M is the intersection of a ball and an ellipsoid)

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

Hi,

I have an elementary question concerning an extremal problem:

Given a manifold $M$:={$(x_1, x_2, x_3) $ | $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 = c$ and $\frac{x_1^2}{a_1^2} + \frac{x_2^2}{a_2^2} + \frac{x_3^2}{a_3^2}= d$ and max($a_1, a_2, a_3$) $> \sqrt{c} >$ min($a_1, a_2, a_3$) } consider an arbitrary point P($\tilde{x}_1, \tilde{x}_2, \tilde{x}_3$) with $M \cap P = \emptyset$.

Now I'm interested in the minimal distance between P and M. My idea was to use Lagrange:

Minimize f:= $||(\tilde{x}_1, \tilde{x}_2, \tilde{x}_3)-(x_1, x_2, x_3)||^2$ with the following boundary conditions:

1) $\varphi_1 := x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 - c =0$

2) $\varphi_2 := \frac{x_1^2}{a_1^2} + \frac{x_2^2}{a_2^2} + \frac{x_3^2}{a_3^2} - d = 0$

=> $\Lambda (x_1, x_2, x_3, \lambda_1, \lambda_2)$ = f + $\lambda_1 \varphi_1 + \lambda_2 \varphi_2$.

Differentiating yields:

i) $2x_1 - 2\tilde{x_1} + 2\lambda_1 x_1 + 2 \lambda_2 \frac{x_1^2}{a_1^2} = 0$

ii) $2x_2 - 2\tilde{x_2} + 2\lambda_1 x_2 + 2 \lambda_2 \frac{x_2^2}{a_2^2} = 0$

iii) $2x_3 - 2\tilde{x_3} +2\lambda_1 x_3 + 2 \lambda_2 \frac{x_3^2}{a_3^2} = 0$

iv) $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 = c$

v) $\frac{x_1^2}{a_1^2} + \frac{x_2^2}{a_2^2} + \frac{x_3^2}{a_3^2}= d$

vi) max($a_1, a_2, a_3$) $> \sqrt{c} >$ min($a_1, a_2, a_3$)

vii) $P \cap M$ = $\emptyset$

Rearranging i)-iii) yields

$x_i\cdot (1+\lambda_1 + \frac{\lambda_2}{a_i^2})=\tilde{x_i}$ , thus
$x_i = \frac{\tilde{x_i}}{1+\lambda_1 + \frac{\lambda_2}{a_i^2}}$

Putting this into iv) and v) you get $\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 (\frac{\tilde{x_i}}{1+\lambda_1 + \frac{\lambda_2}{a_i^2}})^2 = c$ and
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3} ({\frac{\frac{\tilde{x_i}}{a_i^2}}{1+\lambda_1 + \frac{\lambda_2}{a_i^2} } })^2 = d$

Now I wish to solve this for the variables $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, x_1, x_2, x_3$, whereat these variables depend on $a_1, a_2, a_3, c, d, \tilde{x}_1, \tilde{x}_2$ and $\tilde{x}_3$.

I had no idea how to calculate an exact solution, so I wanted to use Newton's Method in order to calculate $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, but I unfortunately did not succeed in achieving the minimum of f, because there are many different solutions for the $\lambda_i$ and I don't know how I can be sure that Newton's Method found the minimal distance between P and M.

Comment: You haven't defined $P$.  IMO your question is better suited to math.stackexchange.com. 

Comment: He defined $P$   as any given point in the space. Anyway, let me just add that Jacobi method, although equivalent to Lagrange method, is often computationally more treatable. 

Comment: I think its an interessesting question wheter there is an exact solution

Comment: It seems a difficult question even for distance to an ellipse in 2D.
Here is an analysis of the 2D problem by David Eberly: http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/DistancePointToEllipse2.pdf 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lagrange method is based on a fact that extrema can occur only at points where the gradient of $f$ is a linear combination of gradients of the constraints -- i.e. at points where $\{\nabla f,\nabla g_1, \nabla g_2 \}$ is linearly dependent with coefficient in front of $\nabla f$ nontrivial. If the constraints are independent ($\nabla g_1 \neq c \nabla g_2$) then you can test this linear depenedence by determinant of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} \partial_x f &\partial_y f &\partial_z f \\\ \partial_x g_1 &\partial_y g_1 &\partial_z g_1 \\\ \partial_x g_2 &\partial_y g_2 &\partial_z g_2\end{pmatrix}$. This gives you the third equations to your constaints $g_1=0$, $g_2=0$. This may be more amenable to numerical solutions. I've tried solving the resulting equations in Maple and it did produce a result, but it is too long to display. For example $z$ variable is a solution of a polynomial of degree 8 with coefficients being polynomial expressions of degree up to 16. One can go further and try to find Groebner basis for this system of polynomial equations, but I don't think that it'll lead to anything more useful than direct numerical solution.

Comment: Apologies for confusion; does your last sentence "try to find Groebner basis for this system of polynomial equations" mean there is no analytic solution to this problem?

Comment: @frank Not necessarily. You can be lucky and get a Gröbner basis that yields solutions in closed form, especially if you allow not only radicals but hypergeometric functions as well. Whether that is something worth pursuing depends on your particular use case.